# Problems getting time value during location update

Tags: android, timer, location

I am having some problems in getting the correct time of a location update using the traditional `onLocationChanged` call.  I have set the `GPS` parameters in `requestLocationUpdates` and the my `getLatitude();` `getLongitude();` and `getAltitude();` values update fine at the appropriate intervals, but my time value seems to lag one reading behind.  I have tried calling the time using `getTime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis();` called when I call `getLatitude();` `getLongitude();` and `getAltitude();` but get the same lag both ways.  Since I am using the time and location to do calculations obviously this lag is a problem.
I thought of implementing a [timer](http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12) that then implements a location call but really do not know how to pull that off.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    /* Get current speed */
        loc.getSpeed();

    /* Assign speed value to double variable in meter/sec, convert to miles/hr, and convert to string*/
        float currentSpeedInMeterPerSecond = loc.getSpeed();
        float currentSpeed = currentSpeedInMeterPerSecond * 2.237f;

        currentSpeedMPHInt = Math.round(currentSpeed);
        currentSpeedString = Integer.toString(currentSpeedMPHInt);

    /* Print out current speed */
        TextView currentSpeedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
        currentSpeedText.setText(currentSpeedString);

    /* Get headwind, frontal area, drag coefficent (Cd), rolling coeffiecent (Cr) */
        mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, prefMode);
        headWindString = mySharedPreferences.getString("keyheadWindString", "0");
        headWind = new Float(headWindString);

        frontalAreaString = mySharedPreferences.getString("keyfrontalAreaString", "6.6");
        frontalArea = new Float(frontalAreaString);

        dragCoefficentString = mySharedPreferences.getString("keydragCoefficentString", "1.15");
        dragCoefficent = new Float(dragCoefficentString);

        riderWeightString = mySharedPreferences.getString("keyriderWeightString", "205");
        riderWeight = new Float(riderWeightString);

        bikeWeightString = mySharedPreferences.getString("keybikeWeightString", "30");
        bikeWeight = new Float(bikeWeightString);

        rollingCoefficentString = mySharedPreferences.getString("keyrollingCoefficentString", "0.0075");
        rollingCoefficent = new Float(rollingCoefficentString); 

    /* get current time and location and speed and altitude*/
        System.currentTimeMillis();
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        loc.getAltitude();

    /* Set start time and location */
        if (i < j) {
            i = i + 1;
            time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            altitudeStart = loc.getAltitude();
            altitudeA = loc.getAltitude();
            latA = loc.getLatitude();
            logA = loc.getLongitude();
            Location.distanceBetween(latA, logA, latB, logB, distance);
        } else { 

        /* Get new location and time*/
            timeNew = System.currentTimeMillis();
            latB = loc.getLatitude();
            logB = loc.getLongitude();
            altitudeB = loc.getAltitude();

        /* Get distance between point A and point B*/
            Location.distanceBetween(latA, logA, latB, logB, distance);
            distanceTraveledMeters = distance[0];           /* distance between A and B in meters*/
            distanceTraveledMiles = distanceTraveledMeters * 0.0006213712f;
            if (distanceTraveledMiles < 0.02f) {
                distanceTraveledMiles = 0f;
            }
         /* Get and find time, total distance, average power , average speed, total Kcal, total elevation diff*/
            timeinterval = timeNew - time1;
            timeintervalSec = timeinterval / 1000f;
            tripTimeTotalmin = tripTimeTotalmin + (timeintervalSec / 60f);
            totalDistance = totalDistance + distanceTraveledMiles;
            averageSpeed = totalDistance / (tripTimeTotalmin / 60f);
            elevChange = (((altitudeB + altitudeA) / 2) - altitudeStart) * 3.2808d;
            elevChangeFloat = (float) elevChange;
            powerElevationChangeWattsAve = ((((riderWeight + bikeWeight) * 32.174f) * elevChangeFloat) / tripTimeTotalmin) * 0.00070234f;
            intervalSpeedMPH = distanceTraveledMiles / (timeintervalSec / 3600f);
            powerAirResistanceWattsAve = (0.5f * dragCoefficent * 0.075f * ((averageSpeed + headWind) * (averageSpeed + headWind)) * frontalArea * (averageSpeed + headWind)) * 0.13295f;
            powerRollingResistanceWattsAve = rollingCoefficent * (riderWeight + bikeWeight) * 32.174f * averageSpeed * 0.062f;
            powerTotalWattsAve = powerElevationChangeWattsAve + powerAirResistanceWattsAve + powerRollingResistanceWattsAve;
            totalKcalBurned = (powerTotalWattsAve * tripTimeTotalmin * 0.01433f) / 0.24f;
            mechBtuUsed = powerTotalWattsAve * tripTimeTotalmin * 0.056869f;

         /*Round off values*/
            totalDistance = totalDistance * 10f;
            totalDistance = Math.round(totalDistance);
            totalDistance = totalDistance / 10f;

            tripTimeMin = Math.round(tripTimeTotalmin);
            timeintervalSec = Math.round(timeintervalSec);
            averageSpeedInt = Math.round(averageSpeed);
            powerTotalWattsInt = Math.round(powerTotalWattsAve);
            totalKcalBurnedInt = Math.round(totalKcalBurned);
            intervalSpeedMPHInt = Math.round(intervalSpeedMPH);
            mechBtuUsedInt = Math.round(mechBtuUsed);
            elevChangeInt = Math.round(elevChangeFloat);

         /*convert to stings*/
            totalDistanceString = Float.toString(totalDistance);
            tripTimeTotalminString = Integer.toString(tripTimeMin);
            averageSpeedString = Integer.toString(averageSpeedInt);
            powerTotalWattsString = Integer.toString(powerTotalWattsInt);
            totalKcalBurnedString = Integer.toString(totalKcalBurnedInt);
            mechBtuUsedString = Integer.toString(mechBtuUsedInt);
            elevChangeString = Integer.toString(elevChangeInt);

         /* Print out */
            TextView totalDistanceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
            totalDistanceText.setText(totalDistanceString);
            TextView tripTimeTotalminText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triptime);
            tripTimeTotalminText.setText(tripTimeTotalminString);
            TextView averageSpeedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avespeed);
            averageSpeedText.setText(averageSpeedString);
            TextView powerTotalWattsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.watts);
            powerTotalWattsText.setText(powerTotalWattsString);
            TextView totalKcalBurnedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.burnedkcal);
            totalKcalBurnedText.setText(totalKcalBurnedString);
            TextView mechBtuUsedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mechbtu);
            mechBtuUsedText.setText(mechBtuUsedString);
            TextView elevChangeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elevchange);
            elevChangeText.setText(elevChangeString);

         /*reset start time and location and interval elevation */
            time1 = timeNew;
            latA = latB;
            logA = logB;
            altitudeA = altitudeB;

         /* check iterations*/
            k = k + 1;
            kString = Integer.toString(k);
            TextView kStringText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.k);
            kStringText.setText(kString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you saving it to know its lagging one behind? And by lagging you mean, you receive an update at time t1, and then at t2, but when you print it, it still has t1?

Comment: I writing it on my screen.  The distances change but the time does not and I can see from the values that the OLD time not the NEW time is being used for the calculations.  Obviously the longer the app runs the smaller the error, but it is still usually too large of an error.

Comment: Where is the calculation done? Is it in the `onLocationChanged` function? I think you're going to have to post some code. I get the feeling the way you are storing/retrieving the time stamps is causing the issue. Can you post at least your `onLocationChanged` code and your calculation code?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best way to do it, but in my app I call on the time of the location update by adding the following lines:

```
public final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        String timeStamp = s.format(new Date());
```

**Edit:**
*I only use the time for logging*

```
07-23 15:50:58.110: I/LocationListener(27513): Time of location change: 03:50:58. Latitude: 35.3597361 Longitude: -76.4046144
```